# Where clause not accepting parameterized value but accept hard coded value in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, uniobjects

In my MVC project, I am using EF where entities (edmx) are generated from Universe DB by making use of Rocket U2.
After the edmx generation, I just felt like it will be the straight forward business of data retrieval with LINQ but it isn't as I stumbled upon a problem straight away with my very simple and first LINQ statement which is as follow

```
1. var test1 = userRepo.QueryAll().Where(x => x.Code == model.UserName);
// generated SQL
FROM User AS Extent1
WHERE (Extent1.Code = ?) OR ((Extent1.Code IS NULL) AND (? IS NULL))}
```

Simple isn't it? Actually it isn't as what I have experienced so far is the SQL statement generated by LINQ is quite weird when I am passing a property value to the where clause while the following statement execute completely fine where I have hard coded value

```
2. var test1 = userRepo.QueryAll().Where(x => x.Code == "JK");
// generated SQL
FROM User AS Extent1
WHERE 'JK' = Extent1.Code}
```

Now, if i return back to my first LINQ query, I noticed, it will work if I enumerate the result before where clause i-e. as follow

```
3. var test = userRepo.QueryAll().ToList().Where(x => x.Code == model.UserName);
```

Can please anyone explain what I am doing wrong here. Although, I can enumerate the result before applying filters but this is not something that would be appropriate for later development where I have to work with joins etc.

Above behavior is same even if work directly with the DbContext rather the individual repository.

Comment: Try adding `Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` to your `DbContext` constructor.

Comment: Great Ivan. Thumbs up for you. Although, I have seen that answer somewhere while I was googling around but didn't try as in my previous projects i used same technique where I was working with SQL DB and never had an issue. Can you explain why such weird behavior?

Comment: Normally there is no problem of not setting it, but looks like your db query provider has a bug (generates incorrect SQL and/or positional parameters - the db providers I'm working use **named** parameters). Setting the flag eliminates `IS NULL` expressions, hence the translator will use single parameter.